# Swift MapKit - add (extra)attribut to annotation?

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I did [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial) MapKit-Tutorial

Everything works fine, but how can I add an extra attribut to my pin?

This is my class Car:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Car: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

let title: String
let subtitle: String
let thirdAttribut: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, subtitle: String, thirdAttribut: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.thirdAttribut = thirdAttribut
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}


var getTitle: String {
    return title
}

var getSubtitle: String {
    return subtitle
}

var getThirdAttribut: String {
    return thirdAttribut
}
```

I want click on an pin and work with this the "thirdAttribut".
My Main-Class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    mapView.delegate = self
    let car = Car(title: "Title", subtitle: "Subtitle", thirdAttribut: "ThirdAttribut", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.906849, longitude: 7.524224) )
    mapView.addAnnotation(car)

    }


func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
  //some config stuff
}



    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    print("Here Comes the Click")

    print(view.annotation.title)
    print(view.annotation.subtitle)
    //view.annotation.thirdAttribut doesn't existis
    //How get I my "thirdAttribut"-Attribut?

    }
```

The third-Attribut mustn't appear in my view. It just contains some data for logic-operations.

I hope u understand me, english isn't my mother tongue.

If u know other ways to code what I want then please tell me. :)

Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An annotation view contains an annotation property. To get that third attribute, you need to cast MKAnnotation to the class you created that adheres to the MKAnnotation protocol, Car.

```
if let carAnnotation = view.annotation as? Car{
    print(carAnnotation.thirdAttrib);
}
```

Comment: so simpel -.- THANK U!